# Magento API SOAP filter website_ids error

Tags: api, magento, soap, magento-1.8

I'm using api soap v1 and calling catalog_product.list everytime I add the website_ids in filter It cause an error.

```
$filter = array( 
'status' => array( '=' => 1 ), 
'type_id' => array( '=' => 'simple' ), 
'website_ids' =>  array('6'),
);
```

2nd question, the args of catalog_product.list is filter and storeView, if I add the store view id or code I display all the product I guess It ignores what I add on it.

```
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list', $filter = null, '6');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.

```
//you're website's id
$result = $client->call($session, 'store.info', '6');
$code = $result['code'];

//here all filters, in 'filters' you can add others filters (like price for example)    
$filters = array(
    'filters' => array(
        'status' => 1, 
        'type_id' => 'simple',
    ),
    'storeView' => "$code"
);

try{
    $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list',$filters);
} catch (Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}
print_r($result);
```

now it works? :)